Model not returning a property's value from another class
Why is it saying 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.
Code in View - this is where I get the 'empty' error:
      @if (Model.appClassificationTxt.division == "test")
    {
        <tr>
    }

My ViewModel:
    public tbl_classification appClassificationTxt { get; set; }

tbl_classification class
     public class tbl_classification 
{
    public int appId { get; set; }
    public string division { get; set; }
    public string app_name { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }
}

"test" should return 2 items, but its saying 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Value cannot be null'. What am I missing.
Expecting that by Model.appClassificationTxt.division == "test", it should return two items from the db table - in the table I have a column named 'division' and if you select the division column it should show test1 and test2 as the two items.

2 Items of what? That doesn't make sense. The property in the VM is a single item one, not a collection. So there is no concept of "2 items" here.

BTW: I'd really recommend to follow C# naming conventions.

What's the exact error message? Maybe "object reference not set to an instance of an object"? If yes, look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

@ Fildor please see above. I added an explanation. @ klaus gutter  yeah, but its supposed to return and cannot be null.
